# DocuSign Get Envelope Status

Tags: docusignapi

I am calling `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/status?envelope_ids="{\"envelopeIds\":[\"903780a3-cfc4-4dd8-a7b0-90b10d783dc9\",\"8a579670-03ec-411c-b781-1091df7590ad\"]}"` with HTTP PUT in c# with httpwebrequest but getting 400 bad request, please help to fix this one issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get status of multiple envelopes:

- Using GET Call,

  GET
        /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/status?envelope_ids=39eddd06-0288-4288-91a1-dbe79c732524,
        5b54c5dd-4c51-4bc1-8251-6e448de34fd4,8f77680d-90fa-4508-9353-0e0707b9518f

  no curly braces in the GET call, just comma separated envelopeIds
- Using PUT Call,

  PUT /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/status?envelope_ids=request_body

  Body should be -

  {
      "envelopeIds":["39eddd06-0288-4288-91a1-dbe79c732524",
     "5b54c5dd-4c51-4bc1-8251-6e448de34fd4","8f77680d-90fa-4508-9353- 0e0707b9518f"] 
  }

PUT call is preferred, because using GET there is a limitation on the number of envelopeIds sent in the URL and you might get an error if you hit that limit, whereas in PUT call all envelopeIds are going in the payload so you will not see any error.

Comment: Thanks Sir, actually i resolved the issue before, you are guiding same as i coded before i was passing json objects of envelope ids rather than request_body.